# Python PyCaret Clustering Script has NameError in PowerBI

Tags: python, powerbi, cluster-analysis, pycaret

I tried to use the following PyCaret Python Script to Cluster my Data, unfortunatly it only gives me NameErrors for "name 'get_clusters' is not defined".

*I installed Anaconda3 2020.09 Windows x64, created an enviroment with Python= 3.7 and activatetd it, installed pycaret and set the pathway to my anaconda pycaret enviroment in the PowerBI setting.
*
I **tried** this script in the Python Script of the Power Query Editor:

```
`from pycaret.clustering import *
 dataset= get_clusters(data=dataset, model='kmeans', num_clusters=3)`
```

I got the script from https://pycaret.gitbook.io/docs/learn-pycaret/official-blog/clustering-analysis-in-power-bi-using-pycaret

But i get this **error**:

```
`DataSource.Error: ADO.NET: Þÿŧĥσŋ ѕçřιρт єгѓθг.
 <pi>NameError: name 'get_clusters' is not defined
</pi>
 Details:
DataSourceKind=Python
DataSourcePath=Python
Message=Þÿŧĥσŋ ѕçřιρт єгѓθг.
<pi>NameError: name 'get_clusters' is not defined
</pi>
ErrorCode=-2147467259`
```

Seemingly it got a problem with: get_clusters

I tried reinstalling Anaconda, using Python=3.11, changing PowerBI pathways and seting the path and environment variables for Python and Anaconda in Windows.
Any help is appreciated!